# access_token expire with in couple of hours and send unauthorized access error - ASP.net web API

Tags: asp.net, cordova, authentication, oauth-2.0, asp.net-web-api2

We have developed an iOS app using visual 2013 apache Cordova tool and its using web APIs (ASP.net web API 2) to authenticate with the server. The access_token expiry date set up for 14 days as default, however, after couple of hours this token will be expired and send unauthorized access error.
Currently the token and the user name stored in the local storage.

public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            // Configure the db context and user manager to use a single instance per request
            app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
            app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationUserManager.Create);

```
        // Enable the application to use a cookie to store information for the signed in user
        // and to use a cookie to temporarily store information about a user logging in with a third party login provider
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());
        app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

        // Configure the application for OAuth based flow
        PublicClientId = "self";
        OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
        {
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/Token"),
            Provider = new ApplicationOAuthProvider(PublicClientId),
            AuthorizeEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/Account/ExternalLogin"),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(14),
            AllowInsecureHttp = true

        };

        // Enable the application to use bearer tokens to authenticate users
        app.UseOAuthBearerTokens(OAuthOptions);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

If you're using IIS, make sure the "machine keys" feature is correctly configured in your `web.config` file.

You can use this Powershell script to generate new static keys:

```
# Generates a <machineKey> element that can be copied + pasted into a Web.config file.
function Generate-MachineKey {
  [CmdletBinding()]
  param (
    [ValidateSet("AES", "DES", "3DES")]
    [string]$decryptionAlgorithm = 'AES',
    [ValidateSet("MD5", "SHA1", "HMACSHA256", "HMACSHA384", "HMACSHA512")]
    [string]$validationAlgorithm = 'HMACSHA256'
  )
  process {
    function BinaryToHex {
        [CmdLetBinding()]
        param($bytes)
        process {
            $builder = new-object System.Text.StringBuilder
            foreach ($b in $bytes) {
              $builder = $builder.AppendFormat([System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture, "{0:X2}", $b)
            }
            $builder
        }
    }
    switch ($decryptionAlgorithm) {
      "AES" { $decryptionObject = new-object System.Security.Cryptography.AesCryptoServiceProvider }
      "DES" { $decryptionObject = new-object System.Security.Cryptography.DESCryptoServiceProvider }
      "3DES" { $decryptionObject = new-object System.Security.Cryptography.TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider }
    }
    $decryptionObject.GenerateKey()
    $decryptionKey = BinaryToHex($decryptionObject.Key)
    $decryptionObject.Dispose()
    switch ($validationAlgorithm) {
      "MD5" { $validationObject = new-object System.Security.Cryptography.HMACMD5 }
      "SHA1" { $validationObject = new-object System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA1 }
      "HMACSHA256" { $validationObject = new-object System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA256 }
      "HMACSHA385" { $validationObject = new-object System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA384 }
      "HMACSHA512" { $validationObject = new-object System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA512 }
    }
    $validationKey = BinaryToHex($validationObject.Key)
    $validationObject.Dispose()
    [string]::Format([System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture,
      "<machineKey decryption=`"{0}`" decryptionKey=`"{1}`" validation=`"{2}`" validationKey=`"{3}`" />",
      $decryptionAlgorithm.ToUpperInvariant(), $decryptionKey,
      $validationAlgorithm.ToUpperInvariant(), $validationKey)
  }
}
```

Simply call Generate-MachineKey in a new Powershell window, and it will generate a new `machineKey` section for you.

```
PS> Generate-MachineKey
<machineKey decryption="AES" decryptionKey="..." validation="HMACSHA256" validationKey="..." />
```